# HTML page's background flickers on page reload when using Spring Security

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, spring-security

I found a strange effect in application that uses Spring Security and a background image.
When there is no Spring Security, background image is seamless on page reload, nothing unusual happens. If there is a Spring Security in the application, background image quickly flickers on page reload. The effect is very annoying. Why it happens and is there any way to overcome this problem? Not using Spring Security is not a solution :-)

P.S. In fact, this flickering happens to any image on the page, not only the one used as a background

pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo2</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Main Configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Demo2Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Demo2Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Security Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"/>
</head>
<body>
INDEX PAGE
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
body {
    background: url("background.jpg") no-repeat, fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe the image is really reloaded, because Spring Security disables the cache by default. You could enable the cache.

Comment: Thanks, it was really connected to Spring Security's cache control. I'll try to adjust it